# Python Selenium Getting link_text from an anchor that is inline

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

in selenium how do I correctly write an xpath or css_selector that would
parse html such as

```
<div class="fxg-rte      " style="color:;" data-emptytext="Rich Text">
<p>United States | <a href="https://www.fedex.com/en-us/home.html">English</a>
 | <a href="https://www.fedex.com/es-us/home.html">Español</a></p>
<p>China | <a href="https://www.fedex.com/en-cn/home.html">English</a>
 | <a href="https://www.fedex.com/zh-cn/home.html">简体中文</a></p>
<p>Mexico | <a href="https://www.fedex.com/en-mx/home.html">English</a>
 | <a href="https://www.fedex.com/es-mx/home.html">Español</a></p>
<p>India | <a href="https://www.fedex.com/en-in/home.html">English</a></p>
<p>Canada | <a href="https://www.fedex.com/en-ca/home.html">English</a>
 | <a href="https://www.fedex.com/fr-ca/home.html">Français</a></p>
</div>
```

to do the following:

Find any `<p>` element that contains the text "United States"
then within the element find any `link_text` that has "**English**"
then click that link.

So specifically I want to look at `link_text` only within

tags that meet a
given criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below xpath :

```
//div[@data-emptytext='Rich Text']//p
```

there will be serveral p tags, you may have to use `find_elements` instead of `find_element`.

in code something like this :

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.fedex.com/global/choose-location.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
for names in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//div[contains(@class, 'richtext parbase section')])[1]/descendant::p"):
    print(names.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    if "United States" in names.get_attribute('innerHTML'):
        print("matched")
        lang_href = names.find_element(By.XPATH, "((//div[contains(@class, 'richtext parbase section')])[1]/descendant::p/a[1])[1]")
        lang_href.click()
        break
```

Comment: Hi cruisepandey and thank you for the swift response.

I ran the code and nothing happened, so I added an else statement like so

`else: print("did not find")`
and it did in fact print "did not find" several times.

I then thought to change 
`if names.text =="United States":`
to
`if "United States" in names.text`
But got the following error
`AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'driver'`


Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if this line `print("yes name matched")` did not get printed, then it means we have a problem with xpath which is `//div[@data-emptytext='Rich Text']//p`

Comment: Okay, I will google another way to write the XPATH. If I find the solution (or if I don't) I will post here and let you know.

Comment: Can you open chrome -> dev tools (press F12) -> and then go to elements section and then do CTRL + F and paste `//div[@data-emptytext='Rich Text']//p` and see if the desired `p` tags are getting highlighted  ?  - we can work together on this.

Comment: if `names.text == 'United States'` is found, wouldn't the `link_value` xpath start from that point?  So instead of `(By.XPATH, "//a")` maybe try `(By.XPATH, "./a")`

Comment: Yes, they are being highlighted. I am trying to show you some changes I made to the code but my comment is too long so I will break it up into two posts.

Comment: I changed code to

`for names in browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-emptytext='Rich Text']//p"):
    print(f'found Xpath {names.text}')
    if "United States" in names.text:
        print("yes name matched")
        print(names.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a").get_attribute('href'))
        link_value = names.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a").get_attribute('href')
        if "English" in link_value:
            names.click()`

and it is printing the `print(f'found Xpath {names.text}')` to the console so the XPATH is good.

Comment: But in this line ` print(names.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a").get_attribute('href'))
`


I am getting the error `print(names.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a").get_attribute('href'))
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'driver'`

PS I am sorry that code is so hard to read. This is my first time on SO so this whole thing is a learning experience for me. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: we can fix that, but tell me are we getting United states in `print(f'found Xpath {names.text}')` ?

Comment: I am sorry, I said it was not found, however it  **WAS** found just at the end.

Comment: Is there a way I can see URL ?

Comment: okay, it means that we just have to fix this line `link_value = names.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a").get_attribute('href')` right ?

Comment: I do believe so yes.

Comment: Where do I see those `p` tags in UI ?

Comment: ahh sorry I gave you the 'href' link we are trying to click rather than the link to get to the site so you can see the html. Simply go to fedex.com (you may need to use incognito because you probably have a cookie saying you are United States English now so you won't see the page where you choose that option)

Comment: I got it!
`for names in browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-emptytext='Rich Text']//p"):
    if "United States" in names.text:
        print("yes name matched")
        print(names.find_element_by_link_text("English"))
        link_value = names.find_element_by_link_text("English").click()`

Comment: @cruisepandey if you want to change your code to mine or something similar (maybe something more pythonic since I am such a beginner and probably wrote it bad) I will upvote it as the correct answer. Thanks so much for sticking this out with me!

Comment: @Minifredx : Check out the code above, I have updated it, it seems to be working fine in my local.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you!